# Conflict in UIGestureRecognizer in custom cell and dequeueCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell (.h, .m, .xib) registered in a UITableView.

Now i need to use a custom UIImage inside the cell and attach to it a Gesture Recognizer (I can't use a UIButton). The problem is that if it at runtime I get a

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (CustomCell) - 
nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'
```

If i remove the gesture the cell works correctly, i believe it's a cocoa bug, i will now try to instantiate it programmatically, but i guess the problem is that the gesture recognizer is on the same herarchy level of the TableViewCell in the xib

[image]

do you know other interface builder workaround?

Comment: Met the same thing. Do you have any further discovery?

Comment: @nickcheng nope, but there are many many other question raised with the same issue i didn't notice, none with an answer. I guess it's a flaw  or done on purpose to avoid gestures on a table view (that already has gesture). Either way not justifyable :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling user interaction on the UIImage and 
adding programmatically a gesture recognizer in the awakeFromNib works

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.delegate = self;
[self.imagePicture addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

But i'd like to know the reason why it is not working rather. I will wait to accept.